# how order data after subscribe

Tags: angular, rxjs

I, this is my snippet:

```js
plageHoraire(): void {
    let desordrePlage = new Array();
    console.log("analyse plage horaire .....");
    for (let i = 0; i < this.plageJour; i++) { //i est le cran
      this.isPlageReserver(this.debJ0H['debJour0H'], i).subscribe(data => {
 
        desordrePlage.push(
          {
            "afficheH": this.trancheDeb + i, "unavailable": data //on check si une des plage son indiponible
          }
        );
        console.log( {"afficheH": this.trancheDeb + i, "unavailable": data});
      });
    }
 
    var tab = [
      {afficheH: 13, unavailable: true}
     ,{afficheH: 9, unavailable: true}
     ,{afficheH: 10, unavailable: true}
     ,{afficheH: 12, unavailable: true}
     ,{afficheH: 8, unavailable: true}
     ,{afficheH: 14, unavailable: true}
     ,{afficheH: 11, unavailable: true}   
     ,{afficheH: 16, unavailable: true}
     ,{afficheH: 15, unavailable: true}
   ];
 
   tab.sort(compare); // on passe la référence à la fonction de comparaison
   console.log(JSON.stringify(tab));
 
   console.log("test réelle");
   console.log(desordrePlage+"DDDDDDDDDDDDD");
 
 
   desordrePlage.sort(compare);
   console.log(JSON.stringify(desordrePlage));
 
   function compare(a, b) {
    if (a.afficheH < b.afficheH) {
      return - 1;
    }
    if (a.afficheH > b.afficheH) {
      return 1;
    }
    return 0;
  }
 
 
 
  }
```

this tab is tidy after tab.sort, the data tab is static,
I would like the desordrePlage, but this data is receive later after subscribe,
this desordrePlage is empty, how i must do for wait the data is here for order the desordrePlage ?

this is console.log:

```js
analyse plage horaire .....
heure.component.ts:96 [{"afficheH":8,"unavailable":true},{"afficheH":9,"unavailable":true},{"afficheH":10,"unavailable":true},{"afficheH":11,"unavailable":true},{"afficheH":12,"unavailable":true},{"afficheH":13,"unavailable":true},{"afficheH":14,"unavailable":true},{"afficheH":15,"unavailable":true},{"afficheH":16,"unavailable":true}]
heure.component.ts:98 test réelle
heure.component.ts:99 DDDDDDDDDDDDD
heure.component.ts:103 []
```

my data is here, this is console.log in a loop:

```html
{afficheH: 8, unavailable: true}
heure.component.ts:79 {afficheH: 9, unavailable: true}
heure.component.ts:79 {afficheH: 11, unavailable: true}
heure.component.ts:79 {afficheH: 10, unavailable: true}
heure.component.ts:79 {afficheH: 12, unavailable: true}
heure.component.ts:79 {afficheH: 13, unavailable: true}
heure.component.ts:79 {afficheH: 14, unavailable: true}
heure.component.ts:79 {afficheH: 15, unavailable: true}
heure.component.ts:79 {afficheH: 16, unavailable: true}
```

this is snippet how call method plageHoraire():

```js
  isDayFree()//on vérifie si la journée est libre si true toute la journée dispo, si false on scan toutes les plage
  {
    //console.log(this._semaine.iBoucle + "==>" + this.debJ0H['debJour0H']);
    this.debJ0H['debJour0H'] + this.trancheDeb * this.parTranche; //le début de la journée
    this.finJour = this.debJ0H['debJour0H'] + this.trancheFin * this.parTranche; //on ajouter la fin de la journée pour toucheFin
    //console.log("DEBUT J=>" + this.debJ0H['debJour0H'] + "FIN J =>" + finJour);
    this._calendarService.dispoWbsRdv(this.debJ0H['debJour0H'], this.finJour).subscribe(data => {
      //on récupère les rendez-vous s'il y en a, s'il y en a pas il sera filtré avec le ngIF = 0
      console.log("array push plageHoraire---------------" + data);
      //data = false;
      //data = true la journée est libre, data = false la journée est pris afficher les plages d'horaire
      data ? this.plageHoraire() : this.pushFalse();//data = false journée dispo on passe à la suivante, data = true il faut analyser la journée
      //on affiche les plages d'horaires de la journée
      //  this._semaine.iBoucle++;//important d'ajouter cette incrémentation
    }, (error) => {
    });
  }
```

We can view methode subscribe()
thank's for reply :)

Comment: You'll be much more likely to get a quality answer if you post the code in english.

Comment: You'll do better if you organize your code better and explain where your code bombs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you push the data inside the subscribe that is in your for-loop, put this:

```
this.isPlageReserver(this.debJ0H['debJour0H'], i).subscribe(data => {


    desordrePlage.push(
      {
        "afficheH": this.trancheDeb + i, "unavailable": data //on check si une des plage son indiponible
      }
    );
     if (i == (this.plageJour - 1)) {   //ADD THIS LINE
        desordrePlage.sort(compare);    // ADD THIS LINE
     }                                 // ADD THIS LINE
    console.log( {"afficheH": this.trancheDeb + i, "unavailable": data});
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing my best since the code isn't in my native language...

When you `.subscribe()` to an HttpClient request, you get the data in the same order that the server sends it. So, you have two options:

1. Sort on the server before returning the result. Obviously this won't work if you don't have access to the server.
2. Sort the values after receiving them, but before using them. See below

Snippet:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.dummyRestApi.getDummyList().subscribe(
    data => {
      this.list = data.sort((a, b) => a - b);
    }
  );
}
```

Plunker:
https://plnkr.co/edit/cphgtpO1PQeihiuL2iw7?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.dummyRestApi.getDummyList().subscribe(
    data => {
      this.list = data.sort((a, b) => a - b);
    }
  );
}
```

this is my webservice, I think i can't do it , because the data is arrive standalone, no in a table.

the web service reponse true if the time is available, and false if the time is not available

```html
$sql="select * from calendar WHERE reserverStartH < $data->fin AND reserverEndH > $data->debut";
//echo json_encode($sql);die;
$pdo = Bdd::getIntance();
$sth =$pdo->prepare($sql);

$sth->bindValue(':reserverStart',$data->debut,PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sth->bindValue(':reserverEndH',$data->fin,PDO::PARAM_INT);

$sth->execute() ? $resultat="requete ok": $resultat= "problème requete"; //debug
$tb = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

empty($tb) ?  $resultat=false : $resultat=true;//si résultat on envoie true, il faut détailler la plage d'horaire
echo json_encode($resultat);//true = affiche détail, false = on inique que toute la journée est libre
```